# Receiving EOF from redis when subscribing to a channel

Tags: go, redis, redigo

Redis has some sort of timeout after 1hr, which raises EOF error when I'm subscribing to some channels.

My Code:

```
pubsub := redis.PubSubConn{Conn: rc}
events := ["controller"]
err = pubsub.Subscribe(events)
if err != nil {
      return
}
for {
    switch v := pubsub.Receive().(type) {
     case error:
        log.Printf("Error: %v", v)
         return
     case redis.Message:
          ...
```

And each hour I see this in the logs (which cause my service to crash):

```
Error: EOF
```

Why do I always receive this EOF message? Should I set some kind of a timeout somewhere?

Versions:
Redis docker => `redis:6.0.9-alpine` (no redis.conf)

redigo => `v1.8.3`

Comment: It looks like the server is configured to close connections after an hour of inactivity.  Fix by sending a PING message to the connection with frequency greater than an hour.  The Redigo pubsub conn example in the documentation shows how to do this.

Comment: Can you share a link to this example please? @CeriseLimón

Comment: See [1](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#example-PubSubConn), [2](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#example-PubSubConn), [3](https://gowalker.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#PubSubConn), ...

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón